# Is using one-way operations in a sessionful contract considered a bad design?

Tags: wcf, web-services, design-patterns

I've read that one-way operations shouldn't be used in a sessionful contract if using *SessionMode.PerSession* instantiation, but it is not a bad design to use one-way operations with sessionful contract when *SessionMode* is either per-call or per-singleton.

Any ideas why one-way operations shouldn't be used with per-session, while they can be used with per-call and per-singleton?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use One-Way operation you don't know if it caused exception on the service. Unhandled exception on the service always faults the channel. If `InstanceContextMode` is set to `PerSession` it faults sessionful channel and it disposes service instance. Because of the one way nature client will not know about it and next call to the service from the same client proxy will end with exception (channel is faulted ...). Client will be only able to call `Abort` on the proxy but he will not know about that. IMO `Single` instancing with session enabled will behave quite similar except it will not dispose service instance.

<strike>This will not happend with `PerCall` instancing because per call instancing uses channel stack for single request processing.</strike> As pointed in comment it will happen in `PerCall` instancing as well because of faulted sessionful channel.

Comment: "This will not happen with PerCall instancing because per call instancing uses channel stack for single request procesing" I assume with PerCall mode any unhandled exception also faults a sesionful channel?But since same sesionful channel is used to  process all requests from this client, won't next call from the same client also end up with an exception ( since channel is faulted and thus can't be used anymore )? If that is the case, then I don't see any benefit of using PerCall over PerSesion. In both cases client won't know that exception happened until it makes another call to the service?

Comment: I believe my reasoning deserves a point;)? Anyhow, can you think of any other reasons why PerCall and Per-Singleton aren't considered a bad design?